# Error: Host Key verification failed, while deploying via SSH and Gitlab CI

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I'm trying to setup CI/CD using GitLab to deploy my web application to DigitalOcean Droplet using SSH.

The problem I'm facing is that, GitLab script is unable to ssh to the server..whereas if I try from my PC, SSH works.

Here's the deploy job that is executed:

```
deploy:
  only:
    - master
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - apt-get install -qq git
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - ls ~/.ssh/
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\t StrictHostKeyChecking no \n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    - ssh-keyscan 159.65.156.240 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - ssh goutam@159.65.156.240 -v - StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'cd ~/wikiquotesapp; git checkout master; git pull;  cd wiki-quotes-server; npm install; npm start:prod'
```

The variable $SSH_KEY has the content of the private key file. Here's the debug output.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
Identity added: (stdin) ((stdin))
$ ls ~/.ssh/
$ [[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\t StrictHostKeyChecking no \n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ ssh-keyscan 159.65.156.240 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
# 159.65.156.240:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
# 159.65.156.240:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
# 159.65.156.240:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ ssh goutam@159.65.156.240 -v - StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'cd ~/wikiquotesapp; git checkout master; git pull;  cd wiki-quotes-server; npm install; npm start:prod'
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6, OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 159.65.156.240 [159.65.156.240] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: SELinux support disabled
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 159.65.156.240:22 as 'goutam'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:+g1ivOXzyPGG093s86TH/B1mEB46wVEgg9ES00vEDgg
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

[image: debug output]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the debug output as text. Don't use pictures of text when you can avoid it.

Comment: okay..I'll try and avoid uploading images next time

Comment: Do you have a passphrase on your private key? Obviously ssh attempts to promt for one: `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address`)

Comment: No I dont have any passphrase for the private key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple...I had forgot to add option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`

So the final script looks like this..

````
deploy: 
only: - master 
stage: deploy
script: 
       - apt-get update -qq
       - apt-get install -qq git 
       - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )' - eval $(ssh-agent -s) 
       - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
       - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
       - echo "$SSH_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null 
       - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\t StrictHostKeyChecking no \n\n" > ~/.ssh/config' 
       - ssh-keyscan 159.65.156.240 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
       - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
       - ssh goutam@159.65.156.240 -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 'cd ~/wikiquotesapp; git checkout master; git pull; cd wiki-quotes-server; npm install; npm start:prod'```
````

Comment: Thank you for this - this solved my problem. One note for anyone else looking at this though: the tutorial I followed had the `StrictHostKeyChecking` already on the line starting with `'[[ -f /.dockerenv ]]` but DID NOT have it on the last line (starting with `ssh goutam@`). It was that second place that fixed it for me